# Python decreasing for loop

Tags: python

Imitating an "increasing" C-styled for loop in Python is very simple:

```
for (int i = A ; i < B ; i += C)
```

can be easily implemented in Python, **Without consuming memory for an array from A to B**, using:

```
for i in range(A, B, C)    # (xrange if Python 2.x)
```

But what about decreasing loops?

How can one imitate C-styled loops such as:

```
for (int i = A ; i >= B ; i -= C)
```

Even using `reversed(range(A, B, C))` constructs an array in the memory, as `reversed` first has to evaluate the whole `range` generator in order to yield its values reversed...

Is there any trick for implementing such a for loop in Python, without constructing an array in the memory? Is there an equivalent for `range` generator, that yields decreasing numbers?

Comment: how about `for i in range(B, A, -C)`

Comment: @akashkarothiya `-C`

Comment: Returns an increasing array, in case that A > B, else returns an empty array

Comment: thanks @DeepSpace for pointing out

Comment: @Chur7U `C` has to be negative. Think of it as a *directional step* not simply a *step*

Comment: but `range` yields nothing when the first parameter is higher or equals to the second parameter

Comment: @Chur7U Again, `C` has to be negative if `B > A`: `list(range(10, 1, -2))
-> [10, 8, 6, 4, 2]`

Comment: just try this: `for i in range(9, 1, -1): print(i)`

Comment: Actually I see now that while `xrange(5, 1)` yields nothing, `xrange(5, 1, -1)` yields `5, 4, 3, 2` !! Nice! thank you!

Comment: In python3 you don't need to use `xrange`, normal `range` suffice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

range takes 3 args `range(start,stop,step)`. The step arg can be negative to iterate backwards.

```
arr = range(10) # range generator in python 3
for i in range(len(arr)-1,0,-1):
    print(arr[i])
9
8
7
6
5
4
3
2
1
```

Note that the start is `len(arr)-1` because lists are 0-indexed so the max idx is 9 for a list of length 10.

Negative steps don't have to be 1 either:

```
for i in range(len(arr)-1,0,-3):
    print(arr[i])    
9
6
3
```

In answer to your second question, you can set arr to be a countdown from the beginning

```
arr = range(10,0,-1)
for a in arr: print(a)

10
9
8
7
6
5
4
3
2
1
```

Comment: I would add that for the general case, `for (int i = A ; i >= B ; i -= C)`, the Python code should be `for i in range(A, B - 1, -C)`

Comment: The 0 here is exclusive.

Answer (score 2):

Just go ahead and call `reversed()` on the result of `range()`. It won't build the whole list because the `range` object has a [`__reversed__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__reversed__) method, which the `reversed()` function detects and uses. Here's how you can see that it has that method:

```
>>> dir(range(3))
['__class__', '__contains__', '__delattr__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__getitem__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__iter__', '__le__', '__len__', '__lt__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__reversed__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', 'count', 'index', 'start', 'step', 'stop']
```

This is assuming you're using Python 3. In Python 2, `range` builds a list in memory regardless of whether you reverse it, although most of the time it makes no performance difference. You can use `xrange`, which is like Python 3's `range`, and also has a `__reversed__` method.